# error inserting to database..working fine in php 5.3.1 but error in 5.2.17

Tags: php

```
function insertVisitorInfoSignIn($att_id, $card_no, $purpose, $block, $level, $staff_email, $pa_email, $staff_id,$dept_id){
    $time_in = getTime();
    $sql = "insert into visitor_history (att_id, card_no, time_in, purpose, block, level, staff_email, pa_email, staff_id,dept_id) 
            values ($att_id, '$card_no', '$time_in', '$purpose', '$block', '$level', '$staff_email', '$pa_email', $staff_id,$dept_id)";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in function insertVisitorInfoSignIn ");
}
```

Comment: String escaping for database context?

Comment: what is the error you are getting , also try using mysqli or PDO as using mysql extensions is deprecated

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Comment: Posting the error that you are receiving along with additional details will help people assist you.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you are using:

```
$sql = "insert into visitor_history 
            ( att_id, card_no, time_in, purpose, block, 
              level, staff_email, pa_email, staff_id, dept_id) 
        values ( $att_id, '$card_no', '$time_in', '$purpose', '$block', 
                 '$level', '$staff_email', '$pa_email', $staff_id, $dept_id)";
```

that should be like this:

```
$sql = "insert into visitor_history 
          ( att_id, card_no, time_in, purpose, block, 
            level, staff_email, pa_email, staff_id,dept_id) 
        values ( '$att_id', '$card_no', '$time_in', '$purpose', '$block', 
                 '$level', '$staff_email', '$pa_email', '$staff_id', '$dept_id')";
```

you missed the `''` in some variables into your query, when passing the value through variable.

we suggest you to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent your DB from SQL injection, and also try using mysqli or PDO as using mysql extensions is deprecated.

Comment: @mario thanks but i am still updating my answer to provide better explanation.

Comment: I'd rather guess the unquoted vars were foremost numeric ids. (OPs actual problem is magic_quotes on one server, but not the other). You should expand your addendum, PDO + mysqli by themselves are useless; only prepared statements would fix this.

Comment: @mario thanks to explain sir, i am here to learn as well thanks to make me correct..